# Let $E \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$, and $f \in R(E)$, then is the fact that $f$ is continuous on $E$ implies $\mu(E) > 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, riemann-integration

## The question

Let $E \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ and $f \in R(E)$, i.e. ($f\colon E \to \mathbb{R}$).
Does the fact that $f$ is continuous on $E$ imply $\mu(E) > 0$?

## Reasoning

I mean the fact that $f$ is continuous on $E$ implies (for $a \in E$) that given $\epsilon > 0$ there is some $\delta > 0$ such that
$$f( B(a, \delta)) \subseteq B(f(a), \epsilon) \Rightarrow \forall x \in B(a, \delta), f(x) \leq f(a) + \epsilon,$$
but this implies that
$$\int_{B(a,\delta)} f(x)dx \leq \int_{B(a,\delta)} (f(a) + \epsilon) dx= (f(a) + \epsilon) \mu(B(a,\delta)),$$
hence in general we cannot have $\mu(B(a,\delta)) = 0$.

## Followup

As a response to the given answer,

[image: An excerpt from a textbook, showing an exercise.]

The part b) implies that since $U_E^\delta(a) \subset E$,
we cannot have $\mu(E) = 0$, doesn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Short answer

No, it does not.

## Example

Any constant function $f$ will be continuous, no matter the set $E$.

## Why does your argument not work?

The definition of continuity talks about metric balls *within the metric space on which $f$ is defined*.
So lets write $B_E$ for the metric balls in $E$, i.e. $B_E(a, \varepsilon) = \{p \in E : d(a, p) < \varepsilon\}$, and $B_R$ for the metric Balls in $\mathbb R^n$, i.e. $B_R(a, \varepsilon) = \{p \in \mathbb R^n : d(a, p) < \varepsilon\}$.

We clearly still have $B_E(a, \varepsilon) = B_R(a, \varepsilon) \cap E \subseteq B_R(a, \varepsilon)$, but we only know $\mu(B_R(a, \varepsilon)) > 0$, whereas $\mu(B_E(a, \varepsilon)) = 0$ is still possible.

## Followup

Yes, by $U_E^\delta(a) = B_E(a, \delta) \subseteq E$ we have $0 < \mu(U_E^\delta(a)) \leq \mu(E)$.

Comment: @onurcanbektas Done. I hope it is understandable enough. It is a common confusion.

Comment: Yeah, it is quite understandable, thanks for your answer.

Comment: Have you seen my edit to the question ?

Comment: @onurcanbektas Only just now. Yes, in this case we know $\mu(E) > 0$ with exactly your argument.

Comment: I'm confused, how does the statement given in the question part $b$ does not contradict with your answer ?

Comment: I mean does the fact that $int(E) \not = \emptyset$ imply $\mu(E) > 0$ ?

Comment: Sets with non-empty interior always have positive measure, since they contain some $B_R(a, \varepsilon)$.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks a lot.

Comment: By the way, for the part $b-)$, does the fact that $\mu (U_E^\delta (a))$ imply that $a$ is an interior point ? I couldn't clearly see this.

Comment: It does not at all.